# Fetch list of cities from entered city and it direction using PHP

Tags: geocoding, geo

I have list of records with city name and it latitude and longitude.now i want to find a list of cities based on entered city and direction (north,south,east,west).e.g, if i enter city Mumbai and select dircetion east then it will display list of east side cities from Mumbai.so how to achieve this task.please if you have any solution then share it with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show that you have tried something...

Comment: maybe this could shed some light [link](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/21/using-the-new-spatial-functions-in-mysql-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/)

Comment: do you already have the list of the cities and directions in your database?

Comment: yes @Amin Jafari.i have all city list with lat/lng value.

Answer (score 0):

A geographic location is expressed as its **latitude** (the distance north of the equator) and the **longitude** (the distance east of the Greenwich [prime meridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_meridian)).

Hence the scenario you describe is merely a matter of selecting the coordinates for Mumbai from your database, and then performing a separate query to return all cities with a higher **longitude** than the discovered value.

Answer (score 0):

the logic is very simple, when the "select" tag containing the cities is "change"d, you need to send an ajax call to your .php file that retrieves the database values and ask it to find the selected city in the other table that contains the direction and list of the cities and then send them back to your .js file and place them in the desired select. with no code to show for, this is the only help I could give you!

Comment: but i want to fetch city list with direction wise using any supported api.now i just have lat/long and city name.